# Homotopy groups of non-contractible manifolds

Tags: algebraic-topology, manifolds, homotopy-theory

Motivated by a proof in a differential geometry book and so far my lack of knowledge in algebraic topology I would like to know the following :

> Is it possible to have a compact non-contractible manifold $M$ with finite fundamental group and trivial homotopy groups $\pi_k(M)$ for $k\geq 2$?

Any help or reference is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I suppose you mean to require your manifold to be connected as well.

Comment: If you call your group $G$, then you're looking for the Eilenberg-Maclane space $K(G,1)$. For example, $K(\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z},1)$ is $\mathbb{R}P^\infty$, which is unfortunately not a finite-dimensional manifold. In fact, what you're looking for can't be achieved by a finite-dimensional manifold, so ana answer would be necessarily a non-compact space.

Comment: "Non-contractible" is superfluous since any contractible space has trivial homotopy groups of all orders.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is impossible even without assuming compactness (assuming you want $M$ to be connected).  Suppose you had such a manifold $M$.  Then $M$ would be a $K(G,1)$ space for the finite nontrivial group $G=\pi_1(M)$.  However, any nontrivial finite group has infinite cohomological dimension, so $M$ would have nontrivial cohomology (with appropriate coefficients) in infinitely many degrees.  This is a contradiction, since if $M$ is a manifold of dimension $n$ it can't have nontrivial cohomology above degree $n$.

Comment: The same argument shows that aspherical manifolds (or more generally, finite-dimensional aspherical CW complexes) have torsion-free fundamental groups.

Answer (score 1):

This can also be achieved through [Miller's theorem](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1996-124-10/S0002-9939-96-03407-7/S0002-9939-96-03407-7.pdf) which states that the based mapping space $Map_*(BG,X)$ is weakly contractible if $G$ is a Lie group with a finite number of path components and $X$ is a nilpotent $CW$ complex with a finite number of cells.

In particular all maps $BG \rightarrow X$ are nullhomotopic.

Your $M$ is a $K(\pi_1(M),1)$ so also a $B\pi_1(M)$. Obviously $G = \pi_1(M)$ viewed as a discrete Lie group has finite number of path components and $M$ also has to be a finite $CW$ complex since it's compact. Thus the identity map $M =BG \rightarrow M$ is nullhomotopic and $M$ is contractible.

Comment: You've not quite quoted Miller's theorem correctly. Note the appearance of the profinite completion in Theorem $2$ of McGibbon's paper. For instance it's known that there are *uncountably* many homotopy classes of maps $BS^1\rightarrow S^3$.